# Rewind capability of Durable functions using isolated worker

Tags: azure-durable-functions, azure-functions-isolated, dotnet-isolated

I know there's a rewind (in preview) capability for durable functions in-proc (available via the `IDurableOrchestrationClient` interface), but I can't find a similar option available on the `DurableTaskClient`. I would like to either be able to rewind or restart a failed activity/instance...how do I do that using having gone the isolated work route? Thank you in advance.